# Выделение текущего выбранного файла в папках проекта в sublime?

Tags: sublime-text

Как настроить, чтобы при клике на дерево файлов и каталогов проекта (слева), текущий выбранный файл как либо выделялся в дереве?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши в основной области, и в контекстном меню выберите пункт Reveal in Side Bar, текущий файл будет подсвечен в дереве файлов и каталогов.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Paskages</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd>, создаём файл ***Default.sublime-theme***, если он ещё не создан, и между `[]` вставляем в него следующий код:

```
        // Свойства имени открытого на данную минуту файла в сайдбаре
        {
            "class": "sidebar_label",
            "parents": [{"class": "tree_row", "attributes": ["selected"]}],
            "color": [128, 0, 128, 255],
            "font.bold": true,
        },
```

Где `color` — цвет открытого на данную минуту файла в [RGBA](http://cuprum.name/page/cvetovaya-model-rgba), а свойство `font.bold` — применять или нет выделение жирным шрифтом, по умолчанию `false`. Допустим, если я открыл в моём проекте файл `examples.html`, соответствующая часть сайдбара будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: Выделение активного файла в сайдбаре]

Спасибо.